# Why write closures if your codebase has a curry function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures, currying

When doing functional programming, if you have a `curry` function available, what's reason is there for writing closures?

**Closure**

```
add = additive => value => value + additive
```

**Curry**

```
add = curry((additive, value) => value + additive)
```

This is the curry function:

```
curry = func => (...args) => (
    args.length >= func.length
    ? func(...args)
    : (...moreArgs) => curry(func)(...args.concat(moreArgs))
)
```

Both `add(1, 2)` and `add(1)(2)`, are possible with this recursive version.

Comment: With manually currying you are more flexible, e.g. `f = (x, y) => z => ...`. `f` is a partially curried function, which is composable. Sometimes the ability to compose is all you need.

Comment: I updated my post. You can be just as dynamic with this particular `curry`.

Comment: Currying makes functions slow.

Answer (score 1):

`curry` is a great way to create closures on-the-fly, but in most cases, it's a lot simpler to write closures instead and `uncurry` where necessary:

- You might not have a `curry` available and writing one is more cumbersome.
- It’s cumbersome to always wrap your functions in `curry`. It creates a lot of indirection and magic where it might not be obvious to other coders, including yourself.
- If micro-optimizations are required, currying will add more function wrappers and logic around your code, ultimately giving it a noticeable slowdown after tens of thousands of calls.